# How is the "Go to source" from TeXstudio any different from "Jump to the line" in Texmaker?

Tags: texstudio, texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I have found many related topics, but none of them seem to have the answer I am looking for.

I have been using Texmaker ever since I migrated from Windows to Linux several years ago. However, many friends of mine use TeXstudio and they claim it to be a better editor than Texmaker.

I myself have strong doubts about it. Mainly because I feel like TeXstudio has some serious issues to compile big projects. In fact, last year I was working on my dissertation and decided to give it a try for TeXstudio. Short story, it took ages to compile the whole *.tex, .bib and all stuff when compared to Texmaker.

Although that turned out to be annoying at the time, I managed to spent a few hours testing the editor and found the feature "Go to source" from Texstudio even more useful than "Jump to the line" in Texmaker. As mentioned before here in the community, "Go to source" is more like a "Jump to the word" feature that is really useful, imho.

That being said, I still prefer Texmaker as editor for overall purposes. Therefore, I wonder if is there any way to make that "Ctrl + Left Click/Jump to the line" more like the "Go to source" from Texstudio. If so, would it have any impact at all for compiling time?

Comment: @KJO I see... so, alternatively, I also like to play around with Texmaker compiler, e.g., switching options from  "PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View PDF" to simpler "PdfLaTeX + View PDF" when I don't need changes for my .bbl file. It seems to help a lot for compiling time in Texmaker. Doing the same thing in TeXstudio doesn't seem to make any big difference. Is there any other way to prevent Texstudio to "run multiple compiles" so I can get better timing for "work'n view" progress?

Comment: @KJO I am asking that because I don't always need Texstudio to recompile indexing and cross-references sorts of things. Like the .bbl example, if I did not add any equations, figs, tabs, etc., some times I just need to run a big paragraph of text containing only simple math symbols or inline equations. If I manage to optimize compiling time, I am willing to migrate to Texstudio just because I liked its "Go to source" feature.

Comment: Only compile the one paragraph you are working on. No need to run the whole thesis every two minutes.